# eval returning variable name instead of undefined. (javascript)

Tags: javascript

**Update**
The code for the function / class is stored in a string which is why I cannot call it directly. The idea is to do introspection on the object and enumerate its data members which works when it is a function but doesn't work when a variable like the one below is eval'ed.

I am trying to evaluate an object in javascript. Something like this.

```
var myObj {
   greet: "Greeting",

   myPrint: function() {
      alert("hello");
   }
};
```

The idea is to be able to run this in eval and get the variable name somehow (myObj) or an object created. I have experimented with various methods using eval but cannot figure this out. This works when I have something like this.

```
function myObj() {
   this.greet  = "Greeting";

   this.myPrint = function() {
      alert("hello");
   }
};
```

Running eval("(" + code + ")"); where code is a string containing the above function returns myObj() to me.

**Update 2**
So basically I want to evaluate something like this. 
eval("var x = 5"); and I am trying to get x. Since its a string being evaluated, even though it gets added to the window namespace, there is no way to decipher it apart from parsing the string. Now this is just a simple example but as I said, it's a little difficult with the 1st piece of code. As I said... 
eval("function test() { return 'hello'; }"); return test() which is similar to what I am expecting for the "var x = 5" statement.

Is there a way to do this similarly for the 1st case which I am missing ?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but the more pressing question is *why* do you want to do this? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Basically I want to introspect all the data members of a class / function. However, the code is actually arbitrary and is pasted into a textbox from where I have to introspect. (Think of it as sort of a feature for an IDE which can show all the data members). I know running arbitrary code is dangerous on eval but this is for a completely different purpose.

Comment: Your `myObj` code isn't valid javascript.  Is it safe to assume it's a typo, or is that actual content you need to somehow evaluate?

Comment: Sorry Chris, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You eval the object without executing the `myPrint` function.

You would need to do something like

```
  myObj.myPrint()
```

To get it to throw the alert.

[edit] To immediately run the `myPrint` function change your code to this:

```
  var myObj = {
    greet: "Greeting",

    myPrint: (function() {
      alert("hello");
    })();
  };
```

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention but the code for the class/function is actually stored in a string. That's the reason I want to use eval on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to dynamically call a callback?

```
var myObj = { // fixed this line of code as it was missing the = 
   greet: "Greeting", // replaced ; with ,

   myPrint: function() {
      alert("hello");
   }
};
console.log(eval(myObj)); // returns obj as expected.
```

If I am correct in my assumption you would need to use bracket notation and EVAL is not needed

So if you were passing a String it would look like:

```
var str = 'myPrint';

var strTwo = 'greet'

myObj[str](); // to execute the function

myObj[strTwo]; // now contains "Greeting"
```

Which would execute that function.

Hope that helps!

Tim

EDIT:

```
var myObj = 'var myObj = { greet: "Greeting", myPrint: function() { alert("hello"); } }'

console.log(eval(myObj));
myObj.myPrint();
```

Then this is what you want if this does not work it means you are not escaping your string correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/XtyHh/

Comment: Thanks Tim, However, the issue is that the entire code for the "var myObj = {...}" is in a string. That is the problem I am facing.

Comment: `myObj[str];` would not execute anything. `myObj[str]();` would.

Comment: jbabey you are correct, I was simply illistrating how to reference any number of methods inside the obj... ie strings would not need () as in greet. Thanks for the update I have edited my example

Comment: That was interesting. But the reason this works is because you have the variable name same as the one inside the string. So in a global eval I guess this one has precedence. However, if you do something like var code = "var myObj ... " it won't work. But that was definitely interesting. However without parsing there is no way to know the variable name.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XtyHh/ - This is what I am trying to do. The eval_code remains undefined. However, I want it to somehow introspect the properties of eval_code and get to its data members.

Comment: I am a very firm believer in if you are relying on EVAL you made need to step back and look at the situation again as most likely there is a better way to accomplish what you are doing. Can you give context to what you are trying to accomplish? To SSARANGI's point if this is dynamically generated string and you do not know what the object contains I do not see how this will be useful. Agian context is key! ssarangi, interesting? executes exactly what you should expect, right?

Comment: Tim, I definitely agree with you on this. eval shouldn't be used. So in this context, we have a textbox where an arbitrary "function/class" can be pasted. The idea is to take that text and then introspect it to find its data members and show them. Kinda like an ide. (But the KEY context is that the class/function could be arbitrary meaning I don't know the name of it. So either I parse out the name or eval it somehow to get the name and then find it). Since it worked for the function example I was hoping if there was a way to do it for "var" too.

Comment: interesting... Will let it bake on the noodle If i think of something I will post back

Answer (score 0):

A code:

```
var sCode = '{ great: "Greating", myPrint: function() { alert("hello!"); } }',
    oObj = eval("(" + sCode + ")");

oObj.myPrint(); // alert "hello"
console.log(oObj.great); // prints "Greating"
```

Comment: Here sCode is defined outside the string. What I am expecting is something like var code = "var x = { greet: 'greeting' };" However, doing this with eval("(" + code" + ")") doesn't work

Comment: you're not allowed to use "var x" with `eval()`